# When it is allowed to omit the dot filter in jq?

Tags: jq

I do not understand, when it is allowed to omit the dot expression.

It is possible to convert every line of raw input into a JSON string:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb" | jq -Rc . 
"a"
"b"
```

In that example it makes no difference, when the dot expression is missing:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb" | jq -Rc 
"a"
"b"
```

Next I can read the output from the first `jq` and slurp it into an array:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb" | jq -Rc . | jq -sc .
["a","b"]
```

Here it makes also no difference, when I omit the dot expression:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb" | jq -Rc . | jq -sc  
["a","b"]
```

But when I omit both dot expressions, I get an usage error and an empty array as result:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb" | jq -Rc | jq -sc 
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
...
[]
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before directly answering the question, I'd like to clarify that:

1. It is always acceptable to specify a filter explicitly.
2. Some versions of jq expect that a filter will be specified explicitly.
3. Different versions of jq behave differently in the absence of an explicit filter.

The main idea guiding jq's evolution with regard to interpreting the absence of a filter intelligently has been that if there's something to read on STDIN, and if a filter has not been specified explicitly, and if it looks like you meant `.`, then assume you did mean `.`.

The answer to the question, then, is that the perplexing behavior noted in the question is a bug in a particular version of jq.

(Or if you like, the perplexing behavior reflects the difficulties that arise when developers seek to endow software with the ability to read your mind.)

By the way, the bug has been fixed:

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.5rc2-150-g1740fd0

$ echo -e "a\nb" | jq -Rc | jq -sc 
["a","b"]
```

Comment: That this is a bug, was also my first idea. But I am not familiar with `jq` so I asked. Maybe there is some magic sense. But from what I have read till now, I can not find any sense either.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the rest of the text

> `Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]`

A filter should be mandatory then, a filter takes an input and produces an output, but in many times you dont need to produce an output and just want the result printed so the default was `.` (see the [issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/220) believe introduced in 1.5, before you must had to include the filter)

so it should be the same if `.` is the default filtering, unfortunately is how pipe is reading stdin and stout. You can read the details in the GitHub issue

> Maybe we should print the usage message only when the program is empty, and stdin and stdout are both terminals? That is, assume . when stdin is not a terminal or when stdout is not a terminal.

so the rule is :

- if you want to be perfectionist always use a filter even if `.` is the filter you want
- if you want the result of your command to be the input of another pipe, you must indicate the filter, again if you just want the same result to be taken as input of the next command.

so the same

`echo -e "a\nb" | jq -Rc > test.txt` will produce an error but `echo -e "a\nb" | jq -Rc . > test.txt` will write the result of the command into the file

Comment: Does not answer the question. The question is: why is it sometimes necessary and sometimes not?

Comment: its necessary when you need to proceed the input as an output into pipe. `.` does nothing really, it just _copying jq's input to its output unmodified_ If you dont need to proceed the result of your command further you can omit the filter, if you need to pipe the result as an input of another command you must put the filter